# How do I bring tests from another test framework into QUnit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I have written a bunch of tests for one JavaScript test framework, and want to pull these into QUnit.

The other framework holds its tests as properties of an object, each holding a test function.  These call an << assertEqual() >> function but I have code rewriting that to pass its arguments on QUnit's << equal() >> function.  I pull the tests into QUnit as follows:

```
for ( var tst_name in otherFrameworkTests ) {
    test(
        tst_name,
        function () {otherFrameworkTests[tst_name]()}
    );
};
```

This runs a QUnit test, under << tst_name >> -- but each of these runs the test in the last property of otherFrameworkTests.  That test runs correctly (fails or passes as expected).

Also: I can run the tests with

```
test("test_name", function () {otherFrameworkTests.test_name()});
```

This works for all the tests in a given file, but it is clumsy and violates DRY.

Why is this happening?  How do I reorganize the code to run all the tests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit-Testing: Q.js & Jasmine.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830033/unit-testing-q-js-jasmine-js)